# Using PHP unset() to remove element in an array leads to inconsistent result

Tags: php, arrays, session

This code:

```
$argh[0]= "nada";
$argh[1]= "A";
$argh[2]= "B";
$argh[3]= "C";
$argh[4]= "D";

for ($i=0;$i < sizeOf($argh);$i++){
    echo "THE CONTENT AT INDEX ". $i . " IS " . $argh[$i];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

yields this output:

```
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 0 IS NADA
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 1 IS A
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 2 IS B 
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 3 IS C
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 4 IS D
```

Using,

```
unset($argh[3]);
$argh = array_values($argh);
```

the output then becomes

```
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 0 IS NADA
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 1 IS A
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 2 IS B 
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 3 IS D
```

which is correct. I apply the same method to a $_SESSION array but the effect is different. Initially, my $_SESSION['sesh'] outputs as:

```
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 0 IS NADA
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 1 IS A
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 2 IS B 
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 3 IS C
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 4 IS D
```

But after executing

```
unset($_SESSION['sesh'][3]);
$_SESSION['sesh'] = array_values($_SESSION['sesh']);
```

the output becomes

```
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 0 IS A
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 1 IS B
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 2 IS D 
THE CONTENT AT INDEX 3 IS NADA
```

Applying unset($x) to a session array seems to result in the deletion of element at index $x, but for some reason it also transfers the value at index 0 to index $x - 1. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: An array is an array.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Rizier123

Comment: You don't show us something here. The code works no matter what the name of the variable is.

Comment: The entire point of my question is to find out why using unset on a non-session array seems to yield output that is different than using unset on a session array.

Comment: Show us your **full** and **real** code + the output of `print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: A `for` loop isn't _"All wrong"_. Does it look a bit dated, and needlessly complex (and can the OP's loops be optimized to avoid calling `sizeof`/`count` too many times)? Yes, sure. But a `for` loop is **not** wrong. Saying that it is is like telling someone he's drawing a circle all wrong because he draws the line in a clock-wards direction, and that he should draw it anti-clock-wards... same difference. With the benefit of `for` loops making it a lot easier to change the array you're iterating over, and the drawback of it breaking for non-sequentially indexed arrays (pro/con)

Comment: If you have 5 elements in your array, unsetting index 3 only reduces your array to 4 elements by removing the value at index 3. You can still echo index 3, only this time it will have the previous value of index 4. There is no logical conflict there.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: That's the downside of a `for` loop, like I mentioned. The downside of `foreach` is that it iterates over objects all the same, and that objects can implement `Traversable` interfaces in such a way that calling `unset` inside a loop can really mess you up: implement `Iterator` interface, and have internal methods rely on the `current`, `next` and `rewind` methods. Now call some methods while iterating over the object and cry

Answer (score 2):

An array in PHP is not like an array in e.g. C.
Your numeric index/key doesn't say anything about the "location" within the array, it's "just" a key like 'foo', 'bar', etc. and it doesn't affect the order of the array if you traverse it from start to end.

e.g.

```
$argh = array();
$argh[1]= "A";
$argh[2]= "B";
$argh[3]= "C";
$argh[4]= "D";
$argh[0]= "nada";

// foreach iterates the array from start to end    
foreach( $argh as $key=>$value ) {
    echo $key, ' ', $value, "\r\n";
}
```

prints

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
0 nada
```

i.e. there *is* a key `0` but its corresponding value is still the last element in the array.
`array_values()` iterates the array just like foreach does, somewhat like

```
$values = array(); $cnt = 0;
foreach( $argh as $value ) {
    $values[$cnt++] = $value;
}
print_r($values);
```

so, your element "nada" gets the highest key because it's the last element in the array.
...and `unset`ting an element in the middle of the array doesn't affect that.
So, your question isn't about "what's special about $_SESSION" but about how you add the elements to _SESSION.